# Puppeteer not using Chrome's Default profile cookies

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I want to access some of my online accounts using puppeteer.

Some of these accounts (such as Soundcloud) have captcha inputs or some sort of bot detection on the login forms.

So ideally I would like to:

Manually open Chrome and log into the services on my default profile.
Then close Chrome and run puppeteer, and use the existing authentication to access my accounts.

I've added the userDataDir (see below) and this seems to open Chrome using my Default profile when it opens Chrome. However it is not logged into the services (in this case Soundcloud). Instead it has logged me out of it. Also - next time I open Chrome I have to log in to the services again.

I'm guessing this is a problem with Puppeteer not using the existing profile's cookies, but rather it clears them out / replaces them.

My code is as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 200,
    executablePath: `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`,
    userDataDir: `/Users/mrbjjackson/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.soundcloud.com/')

  await browser.close();
})();
```

There are plenty of other issues on Stack Overflow that address issues similar to this and I've tried a lot of solutions out there but none have helped me.

Thanks very much.

*edit - just editing to bump this question (2 weeks with no answer)*

Comment: I've got the same issue. I can add that using chrome.exe from the command line gives the exact same behaviour which would lead me to conclude that it's not a puppeteer issue.